# Regular Expression for matching words containing both upper and lowercase letters

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression using Ruby's syntax to match words that contain both upper and lowercase letters.

I was originally going to use `([A-Z]+[a-z]+|[a-z]+[A-Z]+)+` to do that, but it doesn't match all of a word like "YeSmAtCH" or "yEsMaTch", at least according to [this test](https://regexr.com/3o99o).

What expression can I use to match the **entirety** of a word that contains both uppercase and lowercase letters?

Comment: @ctwheels That would also match words containing only lowercase letters or only uppercase letters.

Comment: `(?:[a-z]+[A-Z]|[A-Z]+[a-z])[a-zA-Z]+` or `(?=[A-Z]*[a-z])(?=[a-z]*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: @ctwheels Those work in the RegExr test, do you want to turn that into an answer and I'll accept it if it works when I test it in the wild later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using Ruby, an answer could benefit from lookaheads to assert letters shouldn't be all uppercase or lowercase:

```
\b(?![a-z]+\b|[A-Z]+\b)[a-zA-Z]+
```

[Live demo](http://rubular.com/r/rrzVfZUbMP)

Breakdown:

- `\b` Match a word boundary
- `(?!` Start of negative lookahead

  - `[a-z]+\b` Match a lowercased word
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Z]+\b` Match an uppercased word
- `)` End of lookahead
- `[a-zA-Z]+` Match letters

Answer (score 2):

#### My suggested approach

You can do this without creating a long elaborate regex simply by checking whether or not your string(s) contain(s) an uppercase and lowercase value and by (optionally) ensuring no other character exist in the string. I suggest this approach because I find it easiest to read/maintain.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v1jBVkG1PNrP39cxxNlDIS8/N7EkOUOh0rXYNzEk2UMhMjU417HEGS6SARPxiOUqUCjWK07NSU0uqa6pqFGoULCtU9CPTtStitVXSMxLgQk46kbF6tf@/w8A)

```
s = %w[NOMATCH nomatch yEsMaTcH YeSmAtCh yEsMaTch YeSmAtCH]
p s.select{|x| x =~ /[a-z]/ and x =~ /[A-Z]/}
```

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v1jBVkG1PNrP39cxxNlDIS8/N7EkOUOh0rXYNzEk2UMhMjU417HEGS6SARPxiOUqUCjWK07NSU0uqa6pqFGoULCtU9CPTtStitVXSMxLgQk46kbBBRRBAnFgJZm1//8DAA)

```
s = %w[NOMATCH nomatch yEsMaTcH YeSmAtCh yEsMaTch YeSmAtCH]
p s.select{|x| x =~ /[a-z]/ and x =~ /[A-Z]/ and x !~ /[^a-z]/i}
```

You may also use this variation:

```
s = %w[NOMATCH nomatch yEsMaTcH YeSmAtCh yEsMaTch YeSmAtCH]
p s.select{|x| x =~ /[[:lower:]]/ and x =~ /[[:upper:]]/}
```

Better yet, you can use Unicode classes to allow matching on special characters from other scripts such as `é` and `Ç`:

```
s = %w[NOMATCH nomatch yEsMaTcH YeSmAtCh yEsMaTch YeSmAtCH]
p s.select{|x| x =~ /\p{Ll}/ and x =~ /\p{Lu}/}
```

---

#### The elaborate regex way

If, however, you'd rather a regex-only approach there are several ways to accomplish this:

<sub>The methods below require the `m` flag to be enabled **for online regex editors** if the content is multiline - you don't need to do this in Ruby as it's the default functionality.</sub>

```
^(?:[a-z]+[A-Z]|[A-Z]+[a-z])[a-zA-Z]+$
^(?=[A-Z]*[a-z])(?=[a-z]*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]+$
^(?!(?:[a-z]+|[A-Z]+)$)[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: Sorry for never replying, I'm not actually using Ruby (just the regex syntax for Sublime Text 3 highlighting). I ended up using @revo's lookahead answer because it worked best.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a regex to determine if the word contains a lowercase letter and an uppercase letter, then return the word if it does, else `nil`. That's both simpler and faster than constructing a regex that returns the word if both lowercase and uppercase letters are present.

```
R = /
    (?:      # begin a non-capture group
      [A-Z]  # match an uppercase letter
      [a-z]  # match a lowercase letter
      |      # or
      [a-z]  # match a lowercase letter
      [A-Z]  # match an uppercase letter
    )        # end non-capture group
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode

def both_cases?(word)
  word.match?(R) ? word : nil
end

both_cases?("abBa") #=> "abBa"
both_cases?("ABbA") #=> "ABbA"
both_cases?("abcd") #=> nil
both_cases?("ABCD") #=> nil
```

Comment: I see that OP used almost the same regex you provided in answer but since it doesn't match the whole word they didn't want it (they need a whole match).

Comment: @revo, on re-reading the question I realized your point and modified my method to return the word or `nil`. (I think you posted your comment before that but didn't see it on my phone.) Trying to do what is wanted in a single regex doesn't make sense to me. What do you think?

Comment: From OP I realize that the search is within a text not each word separately according to their live demo.

Comment: No I'm not sure but I'm sure otherwise testing a string over a regex and return whole match is easier than asking a question. Still may be a case for OP to clarify.