# RegEx for checking if capital letters exist in a string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to *extract then correct Capital letters* found in the middle of a word.

I thought of this **regex** but it's not doing exactly what I want, *it's only detecting parts of the wanted results*.

```
[A-Z]([a-z][A-Z]?)+|[a-z]([A-Z][a-z]?)+
```

See here: https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd810vnr

**Example**:

```
Input:
Il CodiCe della mappa non deVe usCire dalla tomba.
```

The regex should identify : **CodiCe , deVe , usCire ..** in order to correct them to lowercase later ..

```
Input:
E il CodiCe per deCifrare la mappa si troVa a Volubilis, ViCino alle roVine romane in MaroCCo.
```

The regex should identify : **CodiCe , deCifrare , troVa , Volubilis , ViCino ,roVine , MaroCCo**

NOTE: Words at the beginning of the segment should be excluded.

Comment: Try `String regex = "\\b(?!\\p{L}\\b)\\p{L}*\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*";`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FkOzzR/1).

Comment: Why did you exclude `Il` but included `Volubilis` while both start with a capital letter and follow lowercase letters?

Comment: Well, I suggested the above regex because I felt you wanted to avoid matching one letter words but it seems there are more hidden rules here. Please explain them in the question.

Comment: If `Il` should be included then this would be a dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946718/regular-expression-for-matching-words-containing-both-upper-and-lowercase-letter

Comment: ```Il``` is at the beginning of the segment ( sentence ) , I think I forgot to mention that , Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex which will match any word having at least one capital letter within, except this will ignore matching first word in any case.

```
\b(?<!^)(?=[a-z]*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]+\b
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h04Sl1/1)**

And here is a Java code that will give you the string where each word having capital letter will be converted to lowercase using `matcher.appendReplacement`

```
List<String> sentenceList = Arrays.asList("Il CodiCe della mappa non deVe usCire dalla tomba.",
        "E il CodiCe per deCifrare la mappa si troVa a Volubilis, ViCino alle roVine romane in MaroCCo.");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(?<!^)(?=[a-z]*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]+\\b");

sentenceList.forEach(x -> {
    System.out.println("Input: " + x);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().toLowerCase());
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println("Lowercased string: " + sb);
    System.out.println();
    });
```

Prints,

```
Input: Il CodiCe della mappa non deVe usCire dalla tomba.
Lowercased string: Il codice della mappa non deve uscire dalla tomba.

Input: E il CodiCe per deCifrare la mappa si troVa a Volubilis, ViCino alle roVine romane in MaroCCo.
Lowercased string: E il codice per decifrare la mappa si trova a volubilis, vicino alle rovine romane in marocco.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing the string with the first letter concatenated with the remainder in lowercase:

```
String input = "E il CodiCe per deCifrare la mappa si troVa a Volubilis, ViCino alle roVine romane in MaroCCo.";
String[] parts = input.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    if (i > 0) sb.append(" ");
    sb.append(parts[i].substring(0, 1)).append(parts[i].substring(1).toLowerCase());
}

System.out.println(sb);

E il Codice per decifrare la mappa si trova a Volubilis, Vicino alle rovine romane in Marocco.
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex does find all those words as well.

```
\b\w+[A-Z]+\w+\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/5lyTG3/4